# Groups style list view in swiftui

Tags: listview, swiftui

Hi I am trying to archive this type of UI. But after running my code I am getting lots of issue.

Here I am using list view with style  GroupedListStyle(). I am taking 3 sections.

isuues I am getting

Lots of space between sections.
section should have some corner radious
A black color separator should be there in between two sections
top portion of navigation has different color. can I make the color default to entire UI.
How to change secone section back ground color as the requirement UI

**Expected UI**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCKmW.png)

**Currently developed UI**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXois.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurrencyData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var currency: String
}

struct CurrencyHistoryView: View {
    var dataArray: [CurrencyData] = [
        CurrencyData(date: "22Aug-3sept", currency: "1365"),
        CurrencyData(date: "23Aug-3sept", currency: "1475"),
        CurrencyData(date: "24Aug-3sept", currency: "1585"),
        CurrencyData(date: "25Aug-3sept", currency: "1695"),
        CurrencyData(date: "26Aug-3sept", currency: "1705"),
        CurrencyData(date: "27Aug-3sept", currency: "1815"),
        CurrencyData(date: "28Aug-3sept", currency: "1925")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                //                ScrollViewReader { _ in
                //                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    SaudiaNavigationView(viewModel: SaudiaNavigationViewModel(isHeaderPinned: true, title: "", subTitle: "", backgroundColor: Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2, shouldShowProfileDetails: true, onScrollLightColor: Theme.BackgroundColor.navigationScrollBackground, onScrollDarkColor: Theme.BackgroundColor.navigationScrollBackground, normalLightColor: Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2, normalDarkColor: Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2, rightButtonType: .Default, onBackButtonTap: {

                    }))
                    .frame(height: 44)
                    //                            ScrollViewReader { _ in
                    //                                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    // Header View

                    //                        Rectangle().fill(Color.black).frame(height: 2)

                    List {
                        Section {
                            VStack(spacing: 2) {
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 9) {
                                            SAGenericText(textString: "RUH", textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .medium, with: .size40))
                                            Image(Theme.ImageIcon.flightIcon)
                                                .resizable()
                                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                                .frame(width: 28, height: 28, alignment: .center)
                                                .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
                                            SAGenericText(textString: "DXB", textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .medium, with: .size40))
                                        }

                                        SAGenericText(textString: "Round Trip", textColor: Theme.TextColor.textBlack70, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size16))
                                    }

                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                                .background(Color(UIColor.white))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                        }
                        Section {
                            VStack {
                            VStack {
                                SAGenericText(textString: "No Flights are availabe for 23 Aug - 3 Nov", textColor: Theme.TextColor.textBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size16))
                                SAGenericText(textString: "Select alternative dates", textColor: Theme.TextColor.textBlack70, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size16))
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150, alignment: .center)

                        Section {
                            ForEach(dataArray) { array in
                                NavigationLink(destination: Text("")) {
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                            SAGenericText(textString: array.date, textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100White90, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                            Spacer()

                                            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 6) {
                                                SAGenericText(textString: "from SAR", textColor: Color.SAColor.colorBlack100WithWhite50, textFont: SAFontConstants.getFont(for: .regular, with: .size14))
                                                    .padding(.bottom, 1)
                                                SAGenericText(textString: array.currency, textFont: SAFontConstants.interSemiBoldLargeText!)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top, 5)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                                        Rectangle().fill(Color.SAColor.colorBlack55White50).frame(height: 1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0)
                    .cornerRadius(7)
                    .padding(.top, -6)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
//                configureEditSearchButton()
                            }
                        }
```

Ui should be as expected. But unable to archive . Anyone please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You are asking too many questions at once. Please deal with each issue on its own, isolating each will also help yourself to focus on solutions.